# How to Remove Redundant Chapter Labels from Both the Chapter Endnotes and TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex, labels, endnotes, remove

The following code produces chapter endnotes at the end the end of each chapter and rename "Notes" as "Chapter I. Endnotes" and "Chapter II Endnotes," respectively:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering everyv%new chapter

\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter  %changes the catcode of @ to 11
\renewcommand\enoteheading{
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother %changes the catcode of @ back to 12

\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand {\chapter}{som}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {\latexchapter*{#3}%
   \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
       {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\latexchapter{#3}}
     {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
       {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\LARGE

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents.}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Chapter I}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I.}}
Some words.\endnote{an endnote.} Some words.\endnote{an endnote.} Some words.\endnote{an endnote.}

\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I. Endnotes.}}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Chapter I. Endnotes} 
\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
\theendnotes

\chapter*{Chapter II}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter II.}}
Some words.\endnote{An endnote.} Some words.\endnote{An endnote.} Some words.\endnote{An endnote.} Some words.\endnote{An endnote.} Some words.\endnote{An endnote.}

\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter II. Endnotes.}}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Chapter II. Endnotes}
\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC:

[image]

And the two Endnote pages are:

[image]

and

[image]

The "Chapter I" and "Chapter II" headings which appear after the Endnotes titles in both the Endnotes sections and in the TOC are redundant and I would like to remove them.

If it matters, I compile the code with `lualatex`.

QUESTION: How may I remove the unwanted "Chapter I" and "Chapter II" labels in the Endnotes sections, as well as in the TOC, keeping only the two which I have manually inserted into the TOC by the commands `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I. Endnotes.}}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I. Endnotes.}}`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

`\theendnotes` starts a new page as a chapter, so  there's no need for a`\newpage` before.

Only four items are listed in the `ToC`: the two chapters and the corresponding `endnotes`.

There are three endnotes in Chapter I, numbered 1 to 3; and six endnotes in chapter II numbered 1 to 6.

[image: a]

[image: b] [image: c]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % added<<<<<<<*    

\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter  %changes the catcode of @ to 11
\renewcommand\enoteheading{
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
    \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
    \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
    \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\pretocmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\setcounter{endnote}{0}}{}{} % reset counter
\makeatother    

\begin{document}
    \LARGE
    
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents.}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter*{Chapter I}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I.}}
    Some words.\endnote{an endnote.} Some words.\endnote{an endnote.} Some words.\endnote{an endnote.}
    
    \renewcommand{\notesname}{Chapter I. Endnotes} 
    \addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
    \theendnotes
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I. Endnotes.}}
    
    \chapter*{Chapter II}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter II.}}
    Some words.\endnote{an endnote.} Some words.\endnote{an endnote.} Some words.\endnote{an endnote.}  Some words.\endnote{an endnote.} Some words.\endnote{an endnote.} Some words.\endnote{an endnote.}
    
    \renewcommand{\notesname}{Chapter II. Endnotes} 
    \addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
    \theendnotes
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter II. Endnotes.}}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer; however, the algorithm does restart the counting at 1. with the beginning of a new chapter.

Comment: @mlchristians Yes but that was the output in the code you posted. If you want consecutive numbering remove `\pretocmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\setcounter{endnote}{0}}{}{} % reset counter`

Comment: I apologize; in my first comment, for some reason "does restart" got typed instead of  "does not restart". I want the endnotes for chapter II to begin with 1. In the MWE, Chapter II has five such endnotes numbered 1-5. In your answer, which has three endnotes for chapter II, I would like them if possible, instead of being numbered 4-6, to be numbered 1-3. Again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @mlchristians Try the code now. I added more footnotes in chapter II  and a figure.

Comment: Many thanks once again for a very helpful answer.